# Retrieve Form Values in Golang Server From Frontend ReactJS Within URL

Tags: reactjs, go, server

I am trying to enter a search query in an input form within my front-end React and retrieve that search query in my Golang server.
I am currently running React on the development server on port 3000 and my Goland server on port 5000.

When I enter a query I see the URL change to localhost:3000/?query="Honda" which is what I want, but it does not show up in the backend server and I think it's because I am using 2 different servers.
I am aware that I can send the data in a json object but I want to know how to retrieve the values from the URL in the Golang server (serve the React files from the golang server).

```
// React front end search bar component 
<Form action="/path/post" id="searchform" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Input value={this.state.query} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="query" />

// React package.json

...
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
...


- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

// golang server
...
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("../client/public", true)))

    ping := router.Group("/path") 
    ping.POST("/post", pingFunc)
    router.Run(":5000")
}

func post(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Request.ParseForm()
        q := FormValue("query")
        fmt.Println(q)
}
...
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a testable and reproducible go program? That will help in getting you the solution quickly.

Comment: Sure, could you explain how exactly I should provide it?